# start mongodb and return to terminal

Tags: mongodb, centos

I can start mongodb on terminal via command

```
./mongod
```

It starts the mongodb server and then display me information that server is running on this port. but It does not give my terminal back. How can I start mongodb and can get terminal back so mongodb is running the background.

Also how to shutdown if its running in background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
./mongod --fork
```

or

```
./mongod &
```

To shutdown you have to send it a TERM signal.

`ps aux | grep mongod` - to find a PID

`kill -TERM PID` - send it a TERM signal, and using the first example we can use the PID file:

`kill -TERM $(cat /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid)`

Also you can shut it down from the shell.

```
$ ./mongo
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer()
```

--

And another method:

```
./mongod --fork --pidfilepath /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

then (please notice the ticks around the cat)

```
kill -9 `cat /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid`
```

Comment: what about this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo   see stopping mongo, is it not a better way?

Comment: @coure2011: oh yeah, forgot about the shell. Never used it.

Comment: What is the '&' part? I don't even know how to call this way of running a program so I can't even google what it does

Answer (score 1):

```
./mongod &
```

You will see a number in the output, something similar to

```
[1]+ ./mongod &
```

To kill the process execute a `kill %1` where 1 is the number between the angular brackets.

Comment: I don't understand what the '&' part does and what is it called. Care to explain or link me to a resourceful link?

Comment: It lets you run the command in background, so you can run a script that takes a lot of time and meanwhile do something else. On the subject: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html